# Extracting coordinates from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this column in my DataFrame

```
df['Y']

0      -37.025.753

1      -37.024.621

2      -37.056.739

          ...     

214     -3.702.631

215    -37.025.369

Name: Longitud, Length: 216, dtype: object
```

1.I tried this:

```
df['Y'] = df.Y.str.rsplit(".",1).str[0]
```

and I get this:

```
df['Y']
0      -37.025
```

2.I tried this:

```
df["Y"] = df["Y"].str.extract("(.+)\.[0-9]+")
```

and I get this:

```
df['Y']
0      -37.025
```

But I would like change dtype in float with 8 decimal like this:

```
df['Y']

0      -37.025753
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a more explicit pattern

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].str.extract(r"(-*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)")
#0  -37.025.753
```

then remove the full stop you don't want, and convert to float:

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].str.replace(r"\.([0-9]{3}$)",r"\1").astype('float64')
#0    -37.025753
```